# Jetpack Infinite Scrolling For Multiple Columns On Same Page?

Tags: plugin-jetpack

Enabling infinite scrolling is as simple as adding this snippet to the theme's functions.php file (where 'content' is the `id` of the container that wraps the posts):

```
add_theme_support( 'infinite-scroll', array(
    'type' => 'scroll',
    'container' => 'content',
    'footer' => false,
) );
```

But what should I do if my website has a multiple column layout where, for instance, one column shows the latest posts, and the other column lists the latest posts from a tag (highlights)? i.e. essentially there are two containers.

I tried these two snippets (see below), and either way, infinite scrolling is only enabled for one column/container.

```
add_theme_support( 'infinite-scroll', array(
    'type' => 'scroll',
    'container' => 'content',
    'footer' => false,
) );

add_theme_support( 'infinite-scroll', array(
    'type' => 'scroll',
    'container' => 'highlights',
    'footer' => false,
) );
```

and

```
add_theme_support( 'infinite-scroll', array(
    'type' => 'click',
    'container' => array( 'content', 'highlights' ),
    'footer' => false,
) );
```

What am I doing wrong?

**NOTE:** If the fact that installing Jetpack requires a wordpress.com account is holding you back, please try [Slim Jetpack](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/slimjetpack/). It even works on a local install of WP, and doesn't require a wp.com account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In an email response, Kris Karkoski, Happiness Engineer (WordPress.com) at Automattic told me, *"Infinite Scrolling with multiple columns is not supported in Jetpack at this time."*

Answer (score 2):

I've checked the source code for Slim Jetpack and this task can not be accomplished without rewriting that plugin.

Here are some hints:

1. You'll have to duplicate line 539 of '/modules/infinity-scroll/infinity.php' stating:

   ```
   jQuery.extend( infiniteScroll.settings.scripts, <?php echo json_encode( $scripts ); ?> );
   ```
2. You'll have to duplicate line 475 of '/modules/infinity-scroll/infinity.js' as this initializes infinite scroll. (Do you see the variable name match?)

   ```
   infiniteScroll.scroller = new Scroller( infiniteScroll.settings );
   ```
3. What's more, you'll have to tweak the module to accept more attributes, or at least `post_type` attribute to be able to determine what post_type to bring for each inifinite loop -- this must be done in both JS and PHP (callback for ajax function).

As I've said, the plugin would have to be rewritten.